# How can I determine the work done by moving a charge?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, charge, work

The lengths of the smaller sides of a right angled triangle are 2m and 3m respectively and a +3C charge is placed at the opposite vertex of hypotenuse then how much work is  done during movement of a +2C charge between other two
vertices?

While preparing for a science olympiad I found this problem as an example. But I can't figure it out. I just need hints/directions so that I can solve it.

Comment: Hi Ramisa and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly (see Picasso-level artwork below), you want to know how much work is done moving the +2C charge from the bottom-right corner to the top of the triangle:
[image: To be seen in the Museum of Modern Art soon]

Work done is just the change in potential energy, so you must first calculate the potential energy of having the +2 C charge at the bottom-right.  Hint: A wise man named Coulomb developed an interesting solution to this problem.

Then calculate the potential energy for when it's at the top.  The difference between these situations is the work done!  It doesn't matter *how* you get from one point to another, just the difference in energy.

In retrospect, a better word might be "productivity" because all you care to measure is the output or the change, whereas "work" implies a measurement of effort as well.  But, we are stuck with our current terminology... this is just one of many examples of bad terminology in physics, but I promise you get used to it. :)

Comment: I worked hard with it and got an answer which is 12.06 joule. I guess I'm wrong.

Comment: It will be even harder for someone to guess what your "hard work" is and where is the mistake. Not too many mind readers around.